# how to get url mime type in qtwebkit networkaccessmanager

Tags: css, mime-types, qtwebkit, qnetworkaccessmanager

I want to get all css urls  in QNetworkAccessManager in order to load the css url from database. 
  The easy solution to get the request's MIME type is by url path extensions, unfortunately this is not always the case. 
  how can I get the link resouce's type(css or img etc) or link resource's attribute like  img/link/rel/type? seems like there is no interface to get CachedResource..